# como llamar un servicio web tipo rest con symfony2(php)?

Tags: php, symfony2, rest

¿Cómo puedo llamar un servicio web tipo REST desde mi aplicación? (está hecha con symfony2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buenas tardes,

Espero que sirve:

http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/jobeet/1_3/es/15?orm=Doctrine